# RestAssured: how to iterate through JSON object and validate each value of key fields

Tags: java, json, rest-assured

```
{
  "body": {
    "format": "json",
    "query": {
      "attributes": [
        {
          "field": "name",
          "order": "none",
          "hidden": false,
          "label": "Computer"
        }
      ],
      "types": [],
      "detail": true,
      "filter": {},
      "size": 5,
      "types_group": "test",
      "context": "newtest"
    },
    "bookmark": {
      "guid": null,
      "processed_time": 1570570800000
    }
  },
  "description": "test new",
  "display_name": "test1",
  "type": "profile",
  "read": "all",
  "write": "all"
}
```

how can I iterate through this JSON Object and validate each value of the key in RestAssured framework.

I want to compare something like this for each key in this JSON:

```
AssertTrue(get("display_name").matches("test1"))
```

Answer (score 1):

As this will be really useful for other so though of Answering it.
However before Answering, there is a Question- How you gonna supply your expected Data set to be compared with Actual response? as you want to validate entire response body so its very important.
I'll explain controlling data from Cucumber Data table; as now a days Rest assured mostly being used with Cucumber(BDD), and so I. (one can use TestNG Data provider also as an efficient way of Test Data m/m, I can explain that too if needed..plz let me know)
Anyways to Answer below is the approach 1:

Sample Feature file:

```html
 When User calls API- "yourAPI" with "Get/Post" method
    Then Server should return response code as "200"
    And Verify Response body contents matched with expected values
      | key     | value                            |
      | status  | 200                              |
      | message | Success                          |
      | result  | Batch got generated successfully |
```

Step Def for above response validation step:

```java
@Then("^Verify Response body contents matched with expected values$")
    public void validateEntireJsonRespBody(DataTable table) throws Throwable {
        List<List<String>> data = table.raw();
        var resBody = response.getBody(); // capture the response in var as per your FW or methods being used
        for(int i = 1; i < data.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println(" Actual Response Value: "+resBody.jsonPath().get(data.get(i).get(0)).toString()+" To be Matched with Expected Data Table value: "+data.get(i).get(1));
                            assertEquals(data.get(i).get(1),resBody.jsonPath().get(data.get(i).get(0)).toString());
      // Or             
        assertThat(resBody.jsonPath().get(data.get(i).get(0)).toString(), equalToCompressingWhiteSpace(data.get(i).get(1)));

        }
```

Or same can be done in this way too- ex2: if you are using cucumber.io instead of info.cukes.

```html
And response includes the following
      | key                              | value              |
      | id                               | 100000002          |
      | batchCode                        | USFP               |
      | batchName                        | US Faster Paym     |
```

Step Def for this one-

```js
    @And("response includes the following$")
    public void response_equals(Map<String,String> responseFields){
        json=response.then();
        System.out.println("JsonBody: "+json.extract().body().asString());

        for (Map.Entry<String, String> field : responseFields.entrySet()) {
            if(StringUtils.isNumeric(field.getValue())){
                json.body(field.getKey(), equalTo(Integer.parseInt(field.getValue())));
            }
            else{
                json.body(field.getKey(), equalTo(field.getValue()));
            }
        }
    }

here var json was declared as of type- ValidatableResponse
```